# Badge modal box having formatting issues in IE

Tags: discussion, bug, badges

Open badges popup box in IE 11, type something in badge search box then clear search box, and formatting is gone.

[image]

I have checked this in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE11, and facing this issue in IE11 only.

Comment: why were you using IE?

Comment: @John like it or not, people still use IE

Comment: @John We are Programmers, even though we don't like IE but still we have to make things compatible with IE.